# How to make a join between 2 tables in Rails that returns the data of both tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, join, helper

I'm trying to join two tables: `Rooms` and `Room_Types` (which have a relationship already). The thing is, I'm trying to do something like:

```
room = Room.all :conditions => ['rooms.id = ?', @room_id],
                :joins      => :room_type

room.to_json
```

..and this JSON is being sent to my view.

However, the JSON is only showing the fields of the Room table and is not including the Room_Type fields, and I need both tables' fields in this JSON. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:joins` only performs a `JOIN`. As in SQL, this does not add the JOINed table's columns to the results. If you want to do that you should use `:include` instead:

```
rooms = Room.all :conditions => [ 'rooms.id = ?', @room_id ],
                 :include    => :room_type
rooms.to_json
```

Or, in Rails 3 parlance:

```
rooms = Room.where(:id => @room_id).include(:room_type).all
rooms.to_json
```

Comment: You may need to use `:include` in your `to_json` options too.

Comment: How can I use :include in my to_json ?

Comment: @content01 Have you checked [the documentation](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M000049)?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Room.joins(:room_type).where(:id => @room_id).select('room_types.foo as foo, room_types.bar as bar')
```